# Scala DSL and Block as function argument

Tags: function, scala, dsl

How can i implement that DSL construction at Scala

```
def objeects(f: => Int):Int {
 println(f)
 // ??? evaluate every function, that f contain in the block. 
}          

manytimes {
 1+1
 2+1
 3+1
}
```

At result we need get one computation for every functions as we pass in block to that method.

```
9
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're after here, but it almost looks like you're trying to reinvent `foldLeft` on a sequence of functions... It's not universal solution, of course, that's just what it looks like from the question's content.

Comment: i need many functions as argument, like (arg* for multi arguments, that are converted to array) but for function in block `{
 1+1
 2+1
 3+1
}         `

Comment: I don't think that's (easily) doable, but I might be wrong, we'll see what other people say.

Comment: I think you should better explain what you want to accomplish.
What is manytimes in your example? What you mean by 'union' (in your case it's just sum, but how that should be guessed by compiler)?
I think it would be more helpful if you will describe what problem you want to resolve rather than how you think solution to it should look like (i.e. why you need this construct in first place?).

Comment: I tried to use `=>Int*` and variations, but it doesn't work. I believe @StanislavSobolev will need to either write a macro or redesign the API.

Comment: So 'union' mean evaluate all functions that are passed to the block 
{ fun1 fun2 ... } Looks like Scala does not support multiple functions argument, unlike variables. I will try learn more about macros, because never encountered them before.

Comment: https://github.com/pniederw/expecty In that project there are multiple functions eval: `expect {
  person.name == "Fred"
  person.age * 2 == 84
  person.say("Hi", "from", "Expecty!") == "Hi from Expecty!"
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of searching i found some really great components, that can help me solve my problem.

```
multifunc { 
            println(1)
            println(2) 
          }
// output
Expr[c.universe.Tree](func.tree)
scala.this.Predef.println(2) // <-- it my case its the second and last elem
class scala.reflect.internal.Trees$Apply // <-- we can apply it as usual
class scala.reflect.internal.Trees$Block
tree<<
class scala.reflect.internal.Trees$EmptyTree$
<empty>
```

Macro for that:
    import scala.language.experimental.macros
    import scala.reflect.macros._
    def multifunc[A](func: => A) = macro _multifunc[A]

```
def _multifunc [A](c: BlackboxContext)(
func: c.Expr[A]
): c.Expr[Unit] = {
import c.universe._

val tree = func.tree match {
  case q"($i: $t) => $body" => q"""
      println($body)
      println($body.getClass)
      $body
    """
  case _ => q""
}


println(func.tree.children.last) // <-- accessor to AST children
println(func.tree.children.last.getClass)
println(func.tree.getClass)
println("tree<<")
println(tree.getClass)
println(tree)
c.Expr(tree)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your block is *one* function:

```
{
 1+1 // calculate 2 and throw away
 2+1 // calculate 3 and throw away
 3+1 // return 4
}
```

This is simply how Scala syntax works, and you can't change it. Indeed, if you could, what would you expect to happen in this case?

```
manytimes {
  val x = 1
  val y = 2
  x + y
}
```

Will

```
manytimes(1+1)(2+1)(3+1)
```

be good enough for your purposes?

Comment: but some frameworks and libs provide block syntax with multiple functions, like i show earlier 
`expect {
  person.name == "Fred"
  person.age * 2 == 84
  person.say("Hi", "from", "Expecty!") == "Hi from Expecty!"
}
` in that project https://github.com/pniederw/expecty

Comment: No. This is all one `Boolean` block which is broken into separate expressions by a macro. See https://github.com/pniederw/expecty/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/expecty/Recorder.scala#L22

Comment: Can you write macro example for separating expressions?

Comment: It's right there: https://github.com/pniederw/expecty/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/expecty/RecorderMacro.scala#L89. Other functions may be useful to you as well, you can start working it out from line 22.